# Prevent DOS attack with multithreaded code

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, networking, tcp

Let me give an overview of my question here:

There are ~ 4000 servers and millions of URLs per server. My code needs to hit each URL and write the response code to HDFS filesystem along with the URL.

Added some part here too :
[Check the number of requests sent to a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729950/check-the-number-of-requests-sent-to-a-webpage)

I am using a producer-consumer model here with 400 threads.  The code has caused a DOS attack to few web servers very recently, I am having a hard time figuring out where the issue here is :

Main class:

```
public void readURLS(final Path inputPath, final Path outputPath) {
    LOG.info("Looking for files to download, queue size: {}, DOWNLOAD_THREADS: {}", queueSize, producerThreads);
    final List<Path> files = HdfsUtils.listDirectory(inputPath, hadoopConf);
    final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(queueSize);
    final UrlConsumerWriter consumerWriter =
            new UrlConsumerWriter(queue, outputPath, hadoopConf);

    LOG.info("Starting download of {} files from: '{}'", files.size(), inputPath);
    final ExecutorService writerPool = DownloadUtils.createWriterPool();
    CompletableFuture<Void> producer = downloadFilesToQueue(files, queue)
            .thenRun(consumerWriter::notifyProducersDone);
    CompletableFuture<Void> consumer =
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(consumerWriter, writerPool)// Cancel download workers if write worker fails
                    .whenComplete((result, err) -> {
                        if (err != null) {
                            LOG.error("Consumer Write worker failed!", err);
                            producer.cancel(true);
                        }
                    });

    writerPool.shutdown();
    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
    LOG.info("Url Validation Job Complete!!!");
}

private CompletableFuture<Void> downloadFilesToQueue(
        final List<Path> files,
        final BlockingQueue<String> downloadQueue
) {
    final ExecutorService pool = DownloadUtils.createDownloadPool(producerThreads);

    final List<CompletableFuture<Void>> workers = files.stream()
            .map(file -> new UrlDownloadWorker(clock, file, hadoopConf, downloadQueue,
                    utils, (validatorImpl.emptyTable())))
            .map(worker -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(worker, pool))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    pool.shutdown();

    final CompletableFuture<Void> allDownloads = CompletableFuture.allOf(workers.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));

    // When one worker fails, cancel all the other immediately
    for (final CompletableFuture<Void> worker : workers) {
        worker.whenComplete((v, err) -> {
            if (err != null) {
                LOG.error("Download worker failed!", err);
                allDownloads.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    return allDownloads;
}
```

PRODUCER CLASS:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        LOG.info("Starting download worker for file: '{}'", file);
        long numLines = 0;

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                file.getFileSystem(hadoopConf).open(file), CHARSET))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               // LOG.info("Thread {} Reading file: '{}'",Thread.currentThread().getName(), file);

                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    throw new InterruptedException();
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                //write into database
                final StatusCode statusCode = utils.validateURL(line);

                if (statusCode != null) {
                        queue.put(builder.append(line)
                                .append(",")
                                .append(statusCode.name()).toString());
                 
                    builder.setLength(0);
                } else {
                    throw new UrlValidationException(
                            "Failed to validate url :'" + line + "'");
                }
                numLines++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DownloadException(file, e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new DownloadException("Interrupted while downloading", file, e);
        }
        LOG.info("Download of {} lines complete for file: '{}'", numLines, file);
    }
```

UrlValidationUtils CLASS:

```
public final class UrlValidationUtils {
    private static final String WEBSITENOTCHECK = "uncheck.org";
    private final Map<String, StatusCode> blockedHosts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final int MAX_REDIRECT = 4;

    public StatusCode validateURL(String url) throws IOException {
        return validate(url, MAX_REDIRECT);
    }

    private StatusCode validate(String url, int maxRedirect) throws IOException {
        URL urlValue = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con;

        if (url.contains(WEBSITENOTCHECK)) {
            blockedHosts.put(urlValue.getHost(), StatusCode.SUCCESS);
        }
        //first check if the host is already marked as invalid
//        if (blockedHosts.containsKey(urlValue.getHost())) {
//            return blockedHosts.get(urlValue.getHost());
//        }
        StatusCode statusCode;
        con = (HttpURLConnection) urlValue.openConnection();

        try {
            int resCode;
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            con.setConnectTimeout(3000); //set timeout to 3 seconds
            con.connect();
            resCode = con.getResponseCode();

            LOG.info("thread name {} connection id {} url {} ", Thread.currentThread().getName(), con.toString(), url);
            if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                statusCode = StatusCode.SUCCESS;
            } else if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER || resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    || resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {
                String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
                if (location.startsWith("/")) {
                    location = urlValue.getProtocol() + "://" + urlValue.getHost() + location;
                }
                statusCode = validateRedirect(location, maxRedirect - 1, con);

            } else {
                blockedHosts.put(urlValue.getHost(), StatusCode.FAIL);
                statusCode = StatusCode.FAIL;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            blockedHosts.put(urlValue.getHost(), StatusCode.UNKOWNHOST);
            statusCode = StatusCode.UNKOWNHOST;
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            blockedHosts.put(urlValue.getHost(), StatusCode.CONNECTION_ISSUE);
            statusCode = StatusCode.CONNECTION_ISSUE;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if an IOException is caught possible reason is SOCKETTIMEOUT
            blockedHosts.put(urlValue.getHost(), StatusCode.SOCKETTIMEOUT);
            statusCode = StatusCode.SOCKETTIMEOUT;
        }
        con.disconnect();
        LOG.info("thread name {} connection id {} url {} ", Thread.currentThread().getName(), con.toString(), url);

        return statusCode;
    }


    private StatusCode validateRedirect(String location, int redirectCount, HttpURLConnection connection)
            throws IOException {
        if (redirectCount >= 0) {
            connection.disconnect();
            return validate(location, redirectCount);
        }
        return StatusCode.FAIL;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to not overload the servers, I suggest waiting a few milliseconds before hitting a batch of urls. For example, after hitting N urls, you could wait 20 ms, then hit the next N.. and so on. The size of the batch (N) would depend on how many requests you know your server can handle in a second. Do you have a Service Level Agreement for them in terms of performance?

Comment: In that case the job would take days/weeks to finish isn't it?

Comment: It depends on how many requests per second your servers can handle. Do you have an SLA for them? If they can handle 1000 requests per seconds, then use batches of 1000. Another idea: do you have millions of unique URLs? Can you maybe reduce the  number of URLs to hit?